# How to add value on custom field using rule action

Tags: 8, rules

I am new to Drupal. Trying to get it work with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

I have added new field (decimal type) to user: `field_user_custom` which I can see in DB as `user__field_user_custom` as a table.

I want to add value to this table on each article update.

I have setup rule as this:

1. Create a Reaction rule
2. React on Event: "After updating content"
3. Action:

   a. Type: set data

   b. Data Value: `@user.current_user_context:current_user:field_user_custom`

   c. Value: 888

However, on article update, this value is not updated. I have tested if the rule is applied with having `System Msg` and it throws the msg but doesn't update the user field.

I doubt my **Data Value** is not correct. Which is why I have tried with this:

- user:field_user_custom

but this didn't help either. What am I missing?

Comment: chances are that you're missing [this](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3616/39516)

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Do you mean I haven't installed this module? Like I said, it show the `sys msg` already.

Comment: which release of it?

Comment: Version 8. Tried with both.

Comment: Sorry but there are multiple ***releases*** for Drupal release 8, so can you be more accurate to indicate something like alfa1, alfa2, betaX, RcY ?

Comment: Drupal Version 8.3.1 and Rules Version 8.x-3.x-dev.

Comment: So a version that is not even a beta version, which is probably also what causes the issue in your question (hence my link in my very first comment). I leave it to others to yes or no consider it "on topic".

Comment: BTW I have also tried with `Rules V 8.x-3.0-alpha2` too. But same issue. I know it's not drupal error, but Rules Error.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. It's actually `@user.current_user_context:current_user.field_user_custom`, per ["Set a data value"?](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2935301).